# How to replicate the Material Ripple animation in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, material-design, vue-transitions

I am trying to replicate the ripple effect from Material Design since the current app I am working on is going to get rid of Quasar; so I'm building all the elements from the ground up.

**This effect:** [image]

I've watched a few videos doing this in just pure CSS and JS and I've tried to convert it into my project, but am getting caught up somewhere. I have the hover effect and the mouse location logging properly, but the ripple effect is just not triggering and I don't know why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

[**CodeSandbox Code**](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-moore-h9nu5?file=/src/components/CButton.vue)

**CButton.vue**

```
<template>
  <button
    @click="onClick"
    :class="[
      'c-btn',
      `c-btn--${kind}`,
      disabled ? `_disabled` : '',
      kind === 'icon-round' ? 'shadow-5' : '',
    ]"
  >
    <transition
      name="ripple"
      @enter="rippleEnter"
      @after-enter="afterRippleEnter"
    >
      <span v-if="ripple" ref="ripple" class="ripple" />
    </transition>
    <div class="_inner">
      <div class="_text">
        <slot>{{ btnText }}</slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CcBtn",
  components: {},
  props: {
    btnText: { type: String },
    kind: { type: String, default: "main" },
    isBusy: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    /**
     * HTML5 attribute
     * @category state
     */
    disabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    color: { type: String, default: "" },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ripple: false,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onClick(e) {
      this.x = e.layerX;
      this.y = e.layerY;
      this.ripple = !this.ripple;
      console.log(`x`, this.x);
      console.log(`y`, this.y);
      console.log(`ripple`, this.ripple);
    },
    rippleEnter() {
      this.$refs.ripple.style.top = `${this.y}px`;
      this.$refs.ripple.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
    },
    afterRippleEnter() {
      this.ripple = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.c-btn
  color: white
  padding: 10px 16px
  border-radius: 4px
  line-height: 1em
  min-height: 2em
  font-weight: bold
  font-size: 16px
  color: White
  cursor: pointer
  border: 1px solid transparent
  transition: background-color 0.5s
  ._inner
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center
  &--main
    background: #9759ff
    min-width: 228px
    border-radius: 100px
    &:hover
      background-color: lighten(#9759ff, 10%)

  &--sub
    background: #f3eefe
    min-width: 228px
    border-radius: 100px
    color: black
    &:hover
      background-color: darken(#f3eefe, 5%)

.ripple
  display: block
  width: 20px
  height: 20px
  border-radius: 10px
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  pointer-events: none
  background-color: rgba(lighten(#9759ff, 20%), 0.8)
  opacity: 0
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(10)
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.4s ease-in-out
  &-enter
    opacity: 1
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0)
</style>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <CButton :btnText="'Button'" kind="main" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <CButton :btnText="'Button'" kind="sub" />
</template>

<script>
import CButton from "./components/CButton.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    CButton,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code for a button to have a ripple effect on click. Using CSS and JS:

```js
function createRipple(event) {
  const button = event.currentTarget;

  const circle = document.createElement("span");
  const diameter = Math.max(button.clientWidth, button.clientHeight);
  const radius = diameter / 2;

  circle.style.width = circle.style.height = `${diameter}px`;
  circle.style.left = `${event.clientX - button.offsetLeft - radius}px`;
  circle.style.top = `${event.clientY - button.offsetTop - radius}px`;
  circle.classList.add("ripple");

  const ripple = button.getElementsByClassName("ripple")[0];

  if (ripple) {
    ripple.remove();
  }

  button.appendChild(circle);
}

const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", createRipple);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background 400ms;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* black with 30% opacity */
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.ripple {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: ripple 600ms linear;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Click For Effect</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and comment! However, I've seen lots of these made in codesandbox or wherever and am trying to convert it to Vue. Not sure where I'm going wrong presently. Perhaps it's because I'm not using keyframes? Anyway, I'll take a deeper look at your comment and see if I can't figure this out